# SQLServer Foreign Key Checks Disabled But Still Can't Drop Table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a SQLServer database which I want to drop a table from. The table has FK constraints, but in this case it doesn't matter because when I repopulate the table, the FKs will be replaced correctly.

I've done `EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"` which gives a message: `sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINTS all" succeded`, but when I try to drop my table I get the following SQL error: `SQL Error: Could not drop object 'myTable' because ti is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint`.

Should the command not have affected my entire database and allowed me to drop the table without an issue? I've also tried doing `EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE myTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"` which results in the same error.

Comment: Why are you trying to drop a table if you are just going to recreate it?

Comment: The table is full of metadata from a program I've run. Changes have been made to address issues with the metadata and it's best to do it from a clean slate.

Comment: No need to drop the table. Just delete the existing data and repopulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOCheck disable the constraints so they won't be enforced.  This would allow you to delete the data without violating the constraint.

Dropping the table would make the constraint definition invalid.  You can't have a constraint that references a table that doesn't exist.  You wouldn't be able to drop the referenced column from the table either while the constraint exists.

If you will be repopulating the table, just delete the table data and reload it.  If you absolutely must drop and recreate the table, you'll need to include the drop & create statements for your foreign key constraints as well.

Note that if you disable the constraint, you'll need to enable using WITH CHECK CHECK (yes twice).  The first check turns the constraint on for new data, the second tells SQL to validate the existing data.  If you only do one, new data will be checked, but the existing data will not be 'TRUSTED', which can affect how SQL will leverage the FK reference in queries.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation. +1 for including alternative ways to achieve my desired outcome. I've done a delete query on the table and it seems to be working as expected now, although it took a while to run!

Comment: Delete is a fully logged transaction and will always take longer than a truncate.  Unfortunately Truncate is considered DDL and cannot be used with FK constraints in place.

Answer (score 3):

> Should the command not have affected my entire database and allowed me
>   to drop the table without an issue?

No.  It doesn't matter what the NOCHECK state is; if there are FK constraints that reference a target table, that target table cannot be dropped.

The only way to drop the table is to first drop the FK constraints that reference it.

Comment: In this case, what is the point in disabling the checks, if the constraints are checked anyway? What is the actual use case meant to be for the command I ran? I'm more used to working with MySQL where the equivalent command would let me drop tables with FK constraints.

Comment: The only point of disabling the checks is to allow you to insert data into the table with the FK that would otherwise not be allowed to be inserted because of the constraint.